# How do I allow _ in this regex for this function

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have a function that works great at converting links, @tags and #hashtags into links, however it does not convert @tags_underscore or #hashtags_underscore, or links with underscore in them into links fully as it leave out the _underscore part of the content.

```
public function convert_instagram_links( $instagram_caption_a_title ) {
    // Create links from @mentions, #hashtags and regular links.
    $instagram_caption_a_title = preg_replace( '/((http)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $instagram_caption_a_title );
    $instagram_caption         = preg_replace( '/[#]+([0-9\p{L}]+)/u', '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $instagram_caption_a_title );
    $instagram_caption         = preg_replace( '/[@]+([0-9\p{L}]+)/u', '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $instagram_caption );
    return $instagram_caption;
}
```

Comment: question improve suggestion: 1. provide minimal: only put 1 regex here 2. give your expected output and actual output 3. tag add what language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to exactly allow Unicode letters, ASCII digits and underscores use `[0-9\p{L}_]` instead of `[0-9\p{L}]`.

However, you can use a mere shorthand `\w` class here:

```
function convert_instagram_links( $instagram_caption_a_title ) {
    // Create links from @mentions, #hashtags and regular links.
    $instagram_caption_a_title = preg_replace( '~https?://[^<>\s]+~i', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $instagram_caption_a_title );
    $instagram_caption         = preg_replace( '/#+(\w+)/u', '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $instagram_caption_a_title );
    $instagram_caption         = preg_replace( '/@+(\w+)/u', '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $instagram_caption );
    return $instagram_caption;
}
echo convert_instagram_links('@tags_underscore or #hashtags_underscore');
// => <a href="https://www.instagram.com/tags_underscore" target="_blank">@tags_underscore</a> or <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hashtags_underscore" target="_blank">#hashtags_underscore</a>
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/6l7E5).

Note that `\w` in a regex with a `u` modifier matches any Unicode letters, digits and also underscores (together with some diacritics and punctuation).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick solution!